# Is it possible to setup Continuous Integration & Continuous Deployment for iOS app development?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I am looking for a way to setup Centralized Continuous Integration and Continuous Deployment for iOS app development. Just like how we do it for Maven or Gradle builds.

I found couple of articles which explains how to achieve this, but for all them are using Xcode to build the iOS application. The key here is Xcode will run only on MacOS.

I found Jenkins Xcode plugin, but it clearly tells,

> Obviously, the build machine has to be an OSX machine with XCode
>   developer tools installed.

Even if we are making one of the developer's OSX machine as Jenkins agent, we can't guarantee that developer's OSX machine will be always connected to Jenkins master. What if somebody else want to build the app and the OSX machine running Jenkins agent is not available?

I found fastlane, but that also seems to automate some of the manual steps like taking screenshots, code signing, releasing the app. It has to be run on only the developers machine if I am not wrong.

What is the generic approach people use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

For CI/CD you can use remote build server like AppCenter from Microsoft (https://appcenter.ms/) or other.
 
And, obviously, without mac machine to build app you can't build your own system CI/CD. Unfortunately, developer can't build app without Apple Machine. 
It is main problem for iOS development. 
In this case, android is better.